# Laptop battery charge rate is very slow

Tags: performance, charging, battery

My laptop battery charge rate is very slow. It charges between 50% - 100% in almost 4, 5 hours. Is it battery or charger problem? I have changed my laptop battery 4 months ago but the charger is 4 years old.
My laptop is HP Compaq 6910P (Core2Duo 2.0, 2GB RAM, 80GB Hard disk).

Comment: Is it an Original (HP approved) battery, or an aftermarket battery

Comment: I don't think its original battery

Comment: Laptops (or the batteries themselves) often reduce the rate of charging for aftermarket batteries to increase lifespan and compensate for lower quality

Comment: Did the problem start around the time you switched batteries?

Comment: The problem started after a month after changing battery